# RubyOnRails Method notation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've started to look into some RubyOnRails (coming from more of a Java / C# background) and I have some questions regarding what the general consensus of notation is.

I've been following the Rails tutorial from (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). 
At 5.10 they're adding some validation to their Article class via

```
validates :title, presence: true, 
                  length: { minimum: 5 }
```

But since `validates` is just a normal method, I could write

```
validates(:title, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 5 })
# or
validates(:title, { :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 5 } })
```

Which of the above notations is the generally accepted one? What are the downsides to either?

(Also, why would I pass the symbol in the second examples, but not in the first one?)

Comment: The pros and cons of different coding styles usually just apply to you and the team working on the code. As such, I think there is just one general rule: Be consistent. NB not necessarily same format in each case, although that is reasonable. Instead, know when you use which format, and if it helps you decide, formulate a rationale. BTW you have copied the example incorrectly from the link, it is `{ minimum: 5 }`

Comment: https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide

Comment: The new syntax requires less keystrokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following syntax is preferred

```
validates :title, presence: true, 
                  length: { minimum: 5 }
```

you are passing in symbols in this one as well because of the new 1.9 hash syntax.  see http://effectif.com/ruby/update-your-project-for-ruby-19-hash-syntax

you could write the same validates method like so

```
validates :title, :presence => true, 
                  :length => { :minimum => 5 }
```

in both examples, `title`, `presence`, `length`, and `minimum` are all symbols

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense then. Everything I've read on symbols thus far has been using colon as prefix. And syntax-highlighting is different in my IDE for both versions :(

Comment: There's a special feature in late versions of ruby, for Hash literals only, where `{foo: "bar"}` is equivalent to `{:foo => "bar"}`.  These things mean the same thing. While the newer shorter version is convenient and more concise for a common case, it is confusing to beginners when there are multiple syntax for the same thing -- it's not just you, it's kinda confusing. You seem to be on the right track, and seem to be understanding what's up, though. All your alternatives are equivalent, most find the versions with less characters and less parens to be more readable --except when they aren't.

Comment: @jrochkind *Some* symbols. You can say `{ :$set => x }` but you can't `{ $set: x }` (but you can `{ '$set': x }` in Ruby 2.2+). I also find it bizarre that people say that the JavaScript-style uses fewer keystrokes while using double quotes for strings. Yes, this is my pet peeve.